# Add values of a list to pandas DataFrame columns based on matching value per DataFrame row

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame which looks like this:

```
            0
2013-09-20  0
2013-09-21  1
2013-09-22  2
2013-09-23  3
2013-09-24  4
2013-09-25  5
2013-09-26  6
2013-09-27  7
2013-09-28  8
2013-09-29  9
...
```

and a list of lists in the following structure:

```
[[0, 125.77, 126.28, 125.77, 126.16],
 [3, 126.06, 126.31, 125.84, 125.86],
 [4, 126.04, 126.93, 126.0, 126.93],
 [5, 126.51, 126.51, 126.0, 126.18],
 [6, 127.63, 128.04, 127.57, 128.04],
 [7, 127.58, 127.8, 126.42, 126.94],
 [10, 126.59, 126.77, 125.14, 125.51],
 [11, 125.38, 125.88, 125.38, 125.88],
 [12, 124.3, 124.3, 123.3, 123.81],
 [13, 123.38, 123.55, 123.09, 123.23],
 [14, 122.71, 122.85, 122.5, 122.79],
 [17, 121.19, 121.74, 121.0, 121.74],
 [18, 122.09, 122.09, 121.12, 121.13],
 [19, 123.31, 123.88, 123.17, 123.58],
 [20, 124.57, 125.83, 124.57, 125.83],
 ...
```

I would like to add the last four values of each list to the DataFrame where the number of the DataFrame's column "0" equals the first value of the respective list in the collection of lists.

E.g.:

```
            0 1      2      3      4
2013-09-20  0 125.77 126.28 125.77 126.16
2013-09-21  1 nan
2013-09-22  2 nan
2013-09-23  3 126.06 126.31 125.84 125.86
...
```

Comment: Recommendations for renaming the title are very welcome..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn your list into a dataframe and use `merge`. In this example, I called your list by the variable name `mylist`:

```
>>> df.merge(pd.DataFrame(mylist), how='left')
   0       1       2       3       4
0  0  125.77  126.28  125.77  126.16
1  1     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
2  2     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
3  3  126.06  126.31  125.84  125.86
4  4  126.04  126.93  126.00  126.93
5  5  126.51  126.51  126.00  126.18
6  6  127.63  128.04  127.57  128.04
7  7  127.58  127.80  126.42  126.94
8  8     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
9  9     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
```

If you need to specify the column names to merge on, use the arguments `left_on=whatever_column_name, right_on=0`.

```
df.merge(pd.DataFrame(mylist), left_on=0, right_on=0,how='left')
```

In your case, the column name of your original `df` is 0, so there is no need.